# Is enrollment certificate a result of an export of the signing certificate

Tags: ssl, digital-signature

Newbie on digital signatures...

Does the certificate that users would import come from me exporting from the signing certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't quite provide enough details in your question, I will try to answer it anyways. What type of digital certificate are you asking about there is various kinds and can be used for various things.

Public key infrastructure aka PKI is used for what you were talking about. If you want to send someone an email or a document and needed to be encrypted you would want to use their public signature so they could unlock it with their private signature. Likewise if someone is sending you something they would need to encrypt it with your public signature so you can lock it with your private signature. Does that make sense and answer your question?

Digital signatures can fit in the same type of PKI where you would sing something with your key and then it would verify you are the correct person that you say you are. There's a lot more to digital signatures so this does not answer your question please post more information.